# Abstract method implementation in component has undefined dependencies

Tags: angular, typescript, abstract-class, angular-components, angular-dependency-injection

Abstract class:

```
export abstract class LanguageChangeAware {

    private sub: Subscription;
    protected language: string;

    protected constructor(protected eventService: EventService) {
        this.sub = eventService.getLang().subscribe(lang => {
            this.language = lang;
            this.load();
        });

        this.load();
    }

    protected ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.sub.unsubscribe();
    }

    protected abstract load();
}
```

Component `NewsPage` implements `LanguageChangeAware` abstract class:

```
export class NewsPage extends LanguageChangeAware {

    public news: Array<NewsItem>;

    constructor(public newsService: NewsService, protected eventService: EventService) {
        super(eventService);
    }

    protected load() {
        console.log('NewsPage - load() - ', this.newsService); // <- undefined

        this.newsService.getNewsItemsList().then(data => {
            this.news = data;
        });
    }
}
```

My problem is that in the `load()` implementation of the `NewsPage` component, the injected dependency `NewsService` is undefined.

---

One possible solution, suggested by user Antoine Boisier-Michaud, was to make the subscription inside the `ngOnInit` method.

Updated version of `LanguageChangeAware`:

```
export abstract class LanguageChangeAware implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    private sub: Subscription;
    protected language: string;

    protected constructor(protected eventService: EventService) {
    }

    public ngOnInit(): void {
        this.sub = this.eventService.getLang().subscribe(lang => {
            this.language = lang;
            this.load();
        });

        this.load();
    }

    public ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.sub.unsubscribe();
    }

    protected abstract load();

}
```

Comment: I believe you have to do your subscription inside an ngOnInit method.

Comment: `super` is called before any assignments. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=export%20class%20NewsPage%20extends%20LanguageChangeAware%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(public%20newsService%3A%20NewsService%2C%20protected%20eventService%3A%20EventService)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super(eventService)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D

Comment: @yurzui that seems logic, I did not realised that. Useful insight.

Comment: @AntoineBoisier-Michaud tried your suggestion. It worked as expected. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor should be used for initializing class members and for dependency injection.  If you have initialization stuff you need to do, you should use the ngOnInit method. When ngOnInit is called, you know all the dependencies have been resolved.

```
export abstract class LanguageChangeAware implements OnInit {

    private sub: Subscription;
    protected language: string;

    constructor(protected eventService: EventService) { }

    protected ngOnInit(): void {
        this.sub = eventService.getLang().subscribe(lang => {
            this.language = lang;
            this.load();
        });

        this.load();
    }

    protected ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.sub.unsubscribe();
    }

    protected abstract load();
}
```

You can read [angular's documentation on lifecycles](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) if you want to learn more about OnInit and other lifecycle hooks.

You can also read [this article](https://www.dev6.com/ngOnInit-and-constructor-in-Angular2) which discusses when to use OnInit and the constructor more specifically.